tablecalendar not showing custom widget for current date in flutter
I am using TableCalendar for showing all data and i am using customWidget for each date.
its showing my customwidget to all dates except current date. i mean to today's date.
what should i change to my code to show my customwidget for today also.
class CalendarWidget extends StatelessWidget {


  final int month;
  final int year;
  CalendarWidget({Key? key,required this.month,required this.year}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TableCalendar(
      headerVisible: false,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.none,
      focusedDay: DateTime(year,month,1),
      firstDay: DateTime(year,month,1),
      lastDay: DateTime(year,month + 1, 0), // This will return last day of current month
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      //availableGestures: AvailableGestures.none,
      daysOfWeekHeight: 30,
      rowHeight: 80,
      calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
        defaultBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) {
          

         return CustomWidget();// this is not showing on current date

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}



You can use todayBuilder
calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
                      defaultBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) {
                        return CustomWidget();
                      },
                      todayBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) {
                        return CustomWidget(); //  this widget will replace Today's cell
                      },
                    ),

